# Magento2: Search by Keyword in logic update for Grid

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, magento2.3.1, product-grid, magento-enterprise-2

In Magento2, For Admin Product Grids, **Search by keyword logic is not working effectively when catalog size is bigger**. (>= 25 lacs)

Due to its searching logic:

1. Searching by SKU
2. Searching by Product Name
3. Searching in short desc, desc (when a full-text search is enabled)
4. Other attributes which have property is_searchable is set

**If we want to Restrict Search by keyword only looks for Sku for Product Grid.**

**What is the best way for doing this without attributes update (via is_searchable property)?**

Thanks,
Nilesh

Comment: Why not changing searchable property?

Comment: We want this for backend only. we do not want impact of this on frontend search and advanced search...