# When attempting to search by keyword in the Magento 2 admin product grid, a gateway (504) timeout occurs

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, search, product-grid

In **Magento version 2.4.4-p2**, I have **13,750** products. I've created a dropdown attribute with four values, which is the required attributes. After assigning attribute data to the products, it is displaying correctly on the frontend.

However, when I try to search for a specific string using the keyword search feature in the Admin Panel Grid under **Catalog > Product**, I got a **504 error**.

```
 SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (`e`.`entity_id` IN(SELECT `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE (`sku` LIKE '%oil%') UNION ALL SELECT `t1`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t1` LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t2` ON t1.entity_id = t2.entity_id AND t1.attribute_id = t2.attribute_id WHERE (t1.attribute_id IN (73, 121)) AND (t1.store_id = 0) AND (IFNULL(t2.value, t1.value) LIKE '%oil%') 
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM (SELECT `catalog_product_entity_int`.`entity_id` FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` WHERE ((attribute_id=152 AND store_id=0 AND value = '821') OR (attribute_id=387 AND store_id=1 AND value = '5032'))) AS inoptionsql))
```

When review the logs, found the above query. Please suggest what was the issue and I can resolve this.

[Magento2: Search by Keyword in logic update for Grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282668/magento2-search-by-keyword-in-logic-update-for-grid)